# String to Calendar object

Tags: java, debugging, calendar

Here is my target format:

> 19 AUG 2011

And I try to convert this string to Calendar object by following code, but variable "date" remains null..

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter ; 
        Date date = null ; 
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
        try {
         date = formatter.parse(returnDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {            
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
```

Does anyone know what's going wrong? Thank You.

FYI, exception msg:

> Unparseable date: "19 Aug 2011"   at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown
>   Source)

But I don't think it is useful...

Comment: not able to reproduce, this is working as expected for me

Comment: The exception absolutely *is* useful, and should *always* be provided when asking a question. The fact that `date` is still null is secondary - this is the exception you need to fix. See the bottom of my answer for a suggested solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something is going wrong with the parsing. You aren't finding out about it because of this:

```
 catch (ParseException e) {            

 }
```

That's basically saying, "I don't care what goes wrong - ignore it." At the *very least* you should be logging the error, and more likely letting the exception bubble up.

Exceptions are an incredibly important diagnostic tool - *don't* just catch them and ignore them.

EDIT: Now that the question's changed, we can see the exception - but the code is still continuing as if nothing's happened. Even if you *do* want to mostly ignore the exception, you need to decide what value you *want* `date` to have if parsing failed. Clearly `null` is unhelpful - so you need to *either* let the exception bubble up (to let the caller know that parsing failed) *or* return some difference value (e.g. a default date, or today, or something like that).

Now, as it happens, letting the exception bubble up makes the code simpler too. It doesn't throw an exception on my machine, but maybe it will on yours:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      Calendar cal = parseReturnDate("19 AUG 2011");
      System.out.println(cal);
    }

    public static Calendar parseReturnDate(String returnDate) 
        throws ParseException {
      SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
      Date date = formatter.parse(returnDate);
      Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
      cal.setTime(date);
      return cal;
    }       
}
```

Note how we don't need to declare variables separately to assigning them values, and that now we're letting the exception bubble up we can just assign `date` its useful value directly.

My *guess* is that your default time zone doesn't use "AUG" as a short month name - but I can't really tell without seeing the exception. If that's the case, you might want to specify the locale when constructing the formatter:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy",
                                                  Locale.US);
```

You *might* also want to specify a time zone.

(As an aside, [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net%29) is a far superior API for date and time handling. If you're doing any significant work with the value afterwards, I'd *definitely* recommend using it over `Date`/`Calendar`.)

Comment: Additionally, in case you were wondering what you should put in that catch phrase, try "e.printStackTrace();". ;)

Comment: I know the error
It is null pointer exception since parsing fail and date remains null
I just remove the exception statement for simplicity,thx

Comment: @Bear: So you've already got your answer - it's because parsing failed. You've decided to try to *ignore* the parsing failure, so what value did you *expect* `date` to have? Why don't you concentrate on fixing the parsing failure? For us to *diagnose* the parsing failure, you should tell us what exception was thrown.

Comment: Thank You. I will take your advise

Answer (score 1):

The SimpleDateFormat depends on the current calendar and the calendar on the locale by default. 
Depending the locale and the calendar probably "AUG" is not a valid text for the month.

AUG is a valid string for US Locale but for example not for ES Locale.

You can force the locale to US adding it to the SimpleDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy",Locale.US);
```

With the US locale you can parse correctly the string if the date has US 2 letter months.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code and it works fine. Try running the following:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Playground {
    
    public static void main(String... args) {
    
        String returnDate = "19 AUG 2011";
        SimpleDateFormat formatter ; 
        Date date = null ; 
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
    
        try {
            date = formatter.parse(returnDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
        System.out.println(date.toString());
    
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
    
        System.out.println(cal.getTime().toString());
    }
}
```

*OUTPUT:*

> Fri Aug 19 00:00:00 CAT 2011
>
> Fri Aug 19 00:00:00 CAT 2011

Comment: @Bear: Are you saying you already *suspected* the problem might be with the locale? If so, why didn't you *tell* use your locale to start with?